# Cannot get property value

Tags: java, spring

```java
@Configuration
public class WebFluxConfig {

    @Bean
    public WebClient getWebClient(@Value("${spring.webflux.base-path}") String baseUrl) {
        return WebClient.builder()
                .baseUrl(baseUrl)
                .defaultHeader(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
                .build();
    }
}
```

added in application.properties

```
spring.webflux.base-path = https://example/api/ (no the real API)
```

Comment: Same code is working for me.

Answer (score 0):

worked with static.webflux.base-path to get the path from application.properties

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).